# ExtJS: Toggling visibility of GridPanel header at runtime

Tags: javascript, extjs, gridpanel

I have a GridPanel which should load a maximum number of resources.
If there are more resources available, than I want to show, I want to enable the panel's header/title to show some texte like "more items available - display cut off".

My problem is:
I can set the header to be hidden oder shown in the config options, but how can I change the visibility at runtime, specificially just when the grid's store has loaded a new set of record, depending on whether the number of records loaded exceeds a certain maximum or not?

If possible, please give your answers compatible to Ext 2.x.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (grid.rendered) {
    grid.header.hide();
    // grid.header.setStyle('display', 'none');
} else {
    grid.on('afterrender', function() {
        grid.header.hide();
        // grid.header.setStyle('display', 'none');
    }, grid, { single: true });
}
```

If you have hideMode to `visibility` use commented code (this with setStyle).